# determine if contents of a vector are mostly positive or negative

Tags: r

I want to test whether a vector contains mostly positive numbers, mostly negative numbers, or an even mix.

Here are  three example vectors.  They're based on real data, which can have outliers in either direction (the +/- `1200`s and +/- `100`s), so just summing or averaging the vectors won't work.

```
z_negative <- c(seq(1, -10, -1), 1200, -100, seq(-10, 1, 1))
z_positive <- c(1, 5, 3, 4, -1200, 100, 8, 9, 11, 5, 10, 8, -1 , 5, 3, 0, -1)
z_tie <- c(1, 1, 1200, 0, 0, 0, -1, -100, -2)
```

I can use `sign` twice, with `mean` or `sum` and achieve what I'm looking for, but the two `sign` functions look strange to me.  Is there a better way (ideally in `base`)?

```
sign(mean(sign(z_negative)))
[1] -1

sign(sum(sign(z_positive)))
[1] 1

sign(sum(sign(z_tie)))
[1] 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the relative counts with `table(sign(...))`:

```r
table(sign(z_negative))
# -1  0  1 
# 21  2  3 
table(sign(z_positive))
# -1  0  1 
#  3  1 13 
table(sign(z_tie))
# -1  0  1 
#  3  3  3
```

You can quantify if something is more or less positive with the ratio of the `"-1"` and `"1"` counts (note the quotes ... don't use `-1` and `1`):

```r
with(list(x = table(sign(z_positive))), x["1"] / x["-1"])
#        1 
# 4.333333 
with(list(x = table(sign(z_negative))), x["1"] / x["-1"])
#         1 
# 0.1428571 
with(list(x = table(sign(z_tie))), x["1"] / x["-1"])
# 1 
# 1
```

Comment: Greg, does this answer your question?